# Access to an "upper" instance of a class from another instance of a different class

Tags: python, oop, field

I'd like to know if there's a way to access to the class (or its fields) where an object is instantiated. Let's say I have:

```
def Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "randomTitle"
        self.anotherField = float()
        self.class2Field = Class2()
```

and the class whose type will be the `class2Field`:

```
def Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.field1 = ""
        self.field2 = ""
        # . . . #
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to access the instance of Class1 from the instance of `Class2` that is declared in `Class1` (meaning, accessing the fields of `Class1` from the variable `self.class2Field` in that `Class1` instance)

I know I can always change the `__init__` in Class2 to accept a `Class1` parameter, but I'd like to know if there's another way of "climbing" through the class hierarchy.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but don't do it. Pass the object explicitly.

Comment: :D Come ooooon :D I just need to access one of the fields to show proper debug messages... Is not gonna hurt anyone... :D :D

Thx for the fast reply, though...

Answer (score 1):

There's no "class hierarchy" to speak of, here. Your `Class1` objects contain `Class2` objects, but your `Class2` objects don't know that.

You could define `self.parent` in `Class2` to be the instance of `Class1` that refers to the object in `self.class2Field`, and have your `Class1` instance passed in by `__init__`:

```
def Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "randomTitle"
        self.anotherField = float()
        self.class2Field = Class2(self)
        # . . . #

def Class2:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.field1 = ""
        self.field2 = ""
        # . . . #
```

It's ugly, it's more overhead, and it requires that `Class2` always be contained (at least the way that I wrote it above), but it might do what you want.

Comment: Yeah... I guess I might have to wrap it... but it's a pity :(
It makes things way more complicated than I expected...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to mess with definition of child class (Class2). Just attach another property to its instance after creating the instance.

```
def Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "randomTitle"
        self.anotherField = float()
        self.class2Field = Class2()
        self.class2Field.parent = self  # <- This is where you attach the pointer to parent.
        # . . . #

def Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.field1 = ""
        self.field2 = ""

    def mess_with_parent(self):
        '''Example of access to instance-level property "parent"'''
        if hasattr(self, 'parent') and self.parent != None: 
            # instead of "!= None" insert your way of checking that .parent is right type
            self.parent.anotherField = 5.0
        # . . . #

a = Class1()
<instance of class1> = a.class2Field.parent
b = a.class2Field
<instance of class1> = b.parent
```

Comment: If you set `z = Class2()`, then you'll get an error when you execute `z.mess_with_parent()` because the attribute `parent` doesn't exist.

Comment: You are correct. (Spent a bit too much time time in JavaScript land, where that would actually work.)

instead of
    if self.parent != None:

there should be something like:
    if 'parent' in dir(self):
        if self.parent != None: # (or put your extra verification logic here):

or: